# RPC_E_CANTCALLOUT_ININPUTSYNCCALL and FileOpenPicker::PickSingleFileAsync

Tags: windows-runtime, c++-winrt

I have the following situation: `FileOpenPicker::PickSingleFileAsync` triggers `Window.Activated` event which has a handler that calls `LowLagMediaRecording::StartAsync`, or `LowLagMediaRecording::FinishAsync` causing the error

> 0x8001010D : 'An outgoing call cannot be made since the application is dispatching an input-synchronous call.'

Relevant questions to `RPC_E_CANTCALLOUT_ININPUTSYNCCALL`:

- [An outgoing call cannot be made since the application is dispatching an input-synchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8839195/an-outgoing-call-cannot-be-made-since-the-application-is-dispatching-an-input-sy)
- [COM outbound call results in "An outgoing call cannot be made since the application is dispatching an input-synchronous call."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6610202/com-outbound-call-results-in-an-outgoing-call-cannot-be-made-since-the-applicat)

I think a solution is:

```
LowLagMediaRecording::FinishAsync();
auto async = FileOpenPicker::PickSingleFileAsync();
// don't call LowLagMediaRecording methods in event handlers while PickSingleFileAsync is executing
auto file = co_await async;
LowLagMediaRecording::StartAsync()
```

But maybe there's another solution. I don't fully understand what's going on yet.

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.capture.lowlagmediarecording?view=winrt-22621#remarks), If you want to restart the recording after calling `FinishAsync`, you will need to call one of the `PrepareLowLagRecord` methods to initialize a new `LowLagMediaRecording` object. Is this part omitted from the question? Could you please provide a [mre] to help us further check the problem for you?

Comment: Undercovers RPC calls to UI object are serialized and put into one (window) message queue. Code running in this message queue (usually implicitly like an RPC event handing code ) cannot call another UI object and wait for its result since it would cause a deadlock. All Windows UI uses this, but it's not obvious when we're dealing with "objects" (WinRT, etc.). There are multiple ways to handle this, either don't block/wait/await the inner calls, or spawn threaded (pool) calls that will allow the "event" call code to exit the message queue safely and block/wait in these threads

Comment: PS: Contrary to what we might think, it's not a COM issue/quirk, it's a COM *feature* that enable UI handling. We can't have full multithreaded RPC calls with UI objects.